# Issue accessing GCP secrets manager using dotnet 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I am using Google.Cloud.SecretManager.V1 in my .NET 5 aspnet core application. I am containerizing application to run as linux container on GCP Cloud run. I get following exception while creating SecretManagerServiceClient

```
//call SDK
SecretManagerServiceClient client = SecretManagerServiceClient.Create();


System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libdl.so' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.UnmanagedLibrary.Linux.dlopen(String filename, Int32 flags)
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.UnmanagedLibrary.LoadLibraryPosix(Func`3 dlopenFunc, Func`1 dlerrorFunc, String libraryPath, String& errorMsg)
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.UnmanagedLibrary.PlatformSpecificLoadLibrary(String libraryPath, String& errorMsg)
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.UnmanagedLibrary..ctor(String[] libraryPathAlternatives)
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.LoadUnmanagedLibrary()
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.LoadNativeMethods()
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension..ctor()
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.Get()
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeMethods.Get()
   at Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment.GrpcNativeInit()
   at Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment..ctor()
   at Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment.AddRef()
   at Grpc.Core.Channel..ctor(String target, ChannelCredentials credentials, IEnumerable`1 options)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.GrpcCore.GrpcCoreAdapter.CreateChannelImpl(String endpoint, ChannelCredentials credentials, GrpcChannelOptions options)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.GrpcAdapter.CreateChannel(String endpoint, ChannelCredentials credentials, GrpcChannelOptions options)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ChannelPool.GetChannel(GrpcAdapter grpcAdapter, String endpoint, GrpcChannelOptions channelOptions, ChannelCredentials credentials)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ChannelPool.GetChannel(GrpcAdapter grpcAdapter, String endpoint, GrpcChannelOptions channelOptions)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ClientBuilderBase`1.CreateCallInvoker()
   at Google.Cloud.SecretManager.V1.SecretManagerServiceClientBuilder.BuildImpl()
   at Google.Cloud.SecretManager.V1.SecretManagerServiceClientBuilder.Build()
   at Google.Cloud.SecretManager.V1.SecretManagerServiceClient.Create()
```

Same code works fine if I use aspnetcore 3.1 image. NET 5 is supposed to be upgrade of .NET core 3.1 and backward compatible. So, I am curious and what could be done to make this code work on .NET 5

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/2397

Comment: Try adding this to your dockerfile: `RUN apt-get install -y libc6-dev`

Comment: Have you solved your issue with recommendations above?

Comment: Yes, issue is solved now. I had to add one more line. RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y libc6-dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this answer to make a solution from the comment section more visible.

As it was suggested by *@John Hanley* and confirmed by *@SmartCoder* this issue was solved by adding to the Docker file lines below:

```
RUN apt-get update -y 
RUN apt-get install -y libc6-dev
```